# LoadRunner AccessViolationException when invoking web.url in C#

Tags: c#, loadrunner

What's the correct syntax to invoke a HTTP Get using the LoadRunner API (VUGEN 9.52.0.0) in C#? The following generates an AccessViolationException:

```
LoadRunner.WebApi web = new LoadRunner.WebApi();
web.url("GoToMyService", "http://path/to/my/service/", new string[0], "LAST");
```

Exception thrown by call to `web.url`:

```
Error: Action.cs(25): System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
   at LoadRunner.WebApiClass.url(String name, String urladdr, Object options, Object extrares)
   at Script.VuserClass.Action() in h:\Personal\_projects\LoadTest\Action.cs:line 25
```

Comment: Oh man, I thought this was going to be about porting the classic game.  :(

Answer (score 0):

One option, which isn't really in the spirit of LoadRunner, is to skip using the LoadRunner API and just use the System.Net APIs:

```
WebResponse response = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://path/to/my/service/").GetResponse();
```

Answer (score -1):

You are engaging in an ethically problematic activity for a performance tester:  You do not point a loaded gun at something that you do not own, manage or control.  LoadRunner is a loaded gun and I am ~~~assuming~~ you don't work for google.   So, just don't

Comment: Don't worry. Worth being clear that I'm not actually running load tests against google.com. In my example code I just replaced the URL for the service I'm developing with something more generic. I have removed my reference to google.com anyway :-)